# Google Analytics reports stopped updating but real time view still shows activity

Tags: google-analytics

I recently started using Google Analytics and everything seemed to be working for the first few days. Then a few days ago the overview stopped working but the real time view seems fine.

I'm using some custom code to send measurement protocol requests via HTTP and that code hasn't changed since it was released. Google Analytics also reports "no data received in the last 48 hours" even though I can see events coming in in real time.

When I called Google's support line they seemed to think it was a problem with how the events are generated. I don't see how that could be the case, since the code hasn't changed, but maybe someone else has an idea?

Here's the code that's sending the event:

```
BOOL SendGoogleAnalytics(char* action, char* category)
{
   if (!IsGoogleAnalyticsEnabled())
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   CStringA strAction = CStringA(action);
   CStringA strCategory = CStringA(category);

   HttpRequest req;
   Http http;

   CStringA strClientID = "0";

   req.UsePost();
   req.put_Path("www.google-analytics.com");

   req.AddHeader("HOST", m_GAHost);
   req.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
   req.put_ContentType("text/html");

   req.AddParam("v",   "1");
   req.AddParam("t",   "event");
   req.AddParam("tid", "UA-xxxxxxxx-xx");
   req.AddParam("cid", strClientID);
   req.AddParam("ni",  "1");
   req.AddParam("an",  "My App");
   req.AddParam("av",  x.x.x.x);
   req.AddParam("ec",  strCategory);
   req.AddParam("ea",  strAction);
   req.AddParam("el",  "dist code 1");
   req.AddParam("ds",  "this code");

   return SendPost(m_GAHost, false, &req);
}
```

Comment: This isn't related to coding, so it should be closed, unless you can supplement your question with some details on the code you used to generate your hits.

Comment: The person I talked to on the support line seemed to think it had something to do with how the events are sent. I don't know how that could be the case but I wanted to post here and see if anyone else had any ideas.

Comment: Can you either post a link to your site or the code you're using to send the MP hits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Google Analytics will only accept a certain number of hits from each client ID in a given time frame. Replacing strClientID above with a per-user GUID string solved the problem.